# MYSQL Query Error from SQLIte3 integration

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have this query which worked in SQLite3 DB Browser which selects customer sales per month based on specific criteria in which %s are filled in by via the user. However, when running the query in MYSQL, i am faced with unknown errors. Could anyone correct the queries logic?

Python ran

```
    select count(orderid), DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%m-%Y")) as month
    from customerOrders INNER JOIN customerDetails ON
    customerDetails.customerid=customerOrders.customerid
    WHERE(product = %s OR 0 = %s) AND
    (milkOptions = %s OR 0 = %s AND (size = %s OR 0 = %s)
    AND (customerDetails.gender = %s OR 0 = %s) AND
    ((YEAR(CURDATE()) - customerDetails.DOB - 1) BETWEEN %s AND %s OR 0 = %s)
    group by orderDate
    order by DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%Y")
```

MYSQL workbench ran:

```
    select count(orderid), DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%m-%Y") 
    from customerOrders INNER JOIN customerDetails ON
    customerDetails.customerid=customerOrders.customerid
    WHERE(product = 'Americano') AND
    (milkOptions = 'Coconut' AND (size = 'Medium')
    AND (customerDetails.gender = 1) AND
    (YEAR((CURDATE()) - customerDetails.DOB) - 1 BETWEEN 17 AND 100)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused.  You have one query or two?  What does "Python ran" mean?

Comment: The parentheses are not balanced.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you don't want to group by `orderdate` and you have an extra closing paren in the `select` and mismatched parens in the `where`.

So:

```
select count(*), date_format(orderDate, '%m-%Y) as month
from customerOrders co inner join
     customerDetails cd
     on cd.customerid = co.customerid
where (product = %s or 0 = %s) and
      (milkOptions = %s or 0 = %s) and
      (size = %s or 0 = %s) and
      (cd.gender = %s or 0 = %s) and
      (year(curdate()) - cd.DOB - 1) between %s and %s OR 0 = %s)
group by month
order by month;
```

You should also qualify *all* column references in the table.  But it is unclear what tables they are coming from, so I can't make specific suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In your workbench query you have a Opening bracket to much

```
select count(orderid), DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%m-%Y") 
from customerOrders INNER JOIN customerDetails ON
customerDetails.customerid=customerOrders.customerid
WHERE(product = 'Americano') AND
(milkOptions = 'Coconut' AND (size = 'Medium')
AND (customerDetails.gender = 1) AND
YEAR((CURDATE()) - customerDetails.DOB) - 1 BETWEEN 17 AND 100);
```

But as Gordon linoff said it it hard to guess your intention Without data and which resuklt you expect.